# Can we use multiple stack in Qt's Undo Framework (Command Pattern )

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, command-pattern

I am having a `QgraphicsView` which contains multiple `QGraphicsItem`. I have some features like `zoom-in`, `zoom-out`, `Hide - Unhide selected item`, `Undo-Redo`.
To implement `Undo-Redo` feature, I am using Qt's `Undo framework` ( Command Pattern).
I want to separate out Undo-Redo feature of `zoom-in/out` with Undo-Redo feature of `Hide/Unhide`.
In a nutshell, I do not want to use same stack for all Undo-Redo feature. Separate stack for `zoom-in/out` and separate stack for `Hide-Unhide`.

> Is separate stack possible ? If yes, then how to do that ?

Below Undo-Redo code is of `Zoom-in/out` and it just for reference purpose.

myCommand.h

```
class myCommand: public QUndoCommand
{
public:
    myCommand();
    myCommand(double scale, QGraphicsScene* scene,QGraphicsView* view);    
private:
       QGraphicsItem* mItem;
       QGraphicsScene* mScene;
       QGraphicsView* mView;
       double scaleFactor;
       void undo();
       void redo();  
}
```

myCommand.cpp

```
myCommand::myCommand(double scale, QGraphicsScene *scene,QGraphicsView* view): mScene(scene),
        mView(view),scaleFactor(scale)
    {}
void guiCommand::undo()
 {
      mView->scale(1/scaleFactor,1/scaleFactor);
 }

void myCommand::redo()
{
     mView->scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
}
```

myView.cpp

```
 void myView::ZoomIn()
    {
        double scaleFactor = 1.1;
        myCommand* command1 = new myCommand(scaleFactor,scene,view);
        undoStack->push(command1);
        view->scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
    }

   void myView::ZoomOut()
   {
      double scaleFactor = 1.1;
      myCommand* command2 = new myCommand(1/scaleFactor,_scene,_view);
      undoStack->push(command2 );
      view->scale(1/scaleFactor,1/scaleFactor);
   }
```

myView.h

```
public:
 QUndoStack* undoStack;
```

Comment: It should be possible but would have manage which operation is done on which stack yourself, and you must ensure that the operations can also be undone, if the other stack has changed the state in between.

Comment: @gerum  Can you tell me, how to implement multiple stack  by taking reference of above code ?

Comment: by having to undoStack variables.  QUndoStack* undoStack1; QUndoStack* undoStack2; And then push the commands to the correct stack.

Comment: @gerum  Your suggestion solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: Note for future readers: Do NOT copy this code (without modifications). The implementation of this undo/redo feature is flavoured. See [Undo-Redo functionality using Command-Pattern in Qt for FitInView feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72159106/undo-redo-functionality-using-command-pattern-in-qt-for-fitinview-feature/72161238) for the correct usage of the Command-Pattern used by Qt's undo framework.